# Remove duplicate variables declaration in xslt using Python

Tags: python, xml, xslt-2.0

Suppose I have this xslt 2.0 code which is generated using altova mapforce

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template name="SDEV:SDEV_NCTS_down_fillUCRC547"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="($var292_CD___C)]">
            <AL586B xmlns="AL586B" >
                <xsl:variable name="var288_cur" as="node()" select="."/>
                <xsl:variable name="var287___as_double" as="xs:double" select="xs:double('6')"/>
            </AL586B>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="(./ns0:AL586B)">
            <AL506C xmlns="AL506C">
                <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                <xsl:variable name="var287___as_double" as="xs:double" select="xs:double('6')"/>
                <xsl:variable name="var1_preparationDateAndTi_as_string" as="xs:string" select="xs:string(xs:dateTime(fn:string($var287___as_double)))"/>
            </AL506C>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you see the variable name `var287___as_double` has been declared twice and this is causing issues. How can I use Python to read this xslt and in each duplicate value that I found to rename it in something like `var287___as_double2`?

And of course whenever this duplicate var was used, to use the new declared var?

For example the new xslt will be something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template name="SDEV:SDEV_NCTS_down_fillUCRC547"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="($var292_CD___C)]">
            <AL586B xmlns="AL586B" >
                <xsl:variable name="var288_cur" as="node()" select="."/>
                <xsl:variable name="var287___as_double" as="xs:double" select="xs:double('6')"/>
            </AL586B>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="(./ns0:AL586B)">
            <AL506C xmlns="AL506C">
                <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                <xsl:variable name="var287___as_double2" as="xs:double" select="xs:double('6')"/>
                <xsl:variable name="var1_preparationDateAndTi_as_string" as="xs:string" select="xs:string(xs:dateTime(fn:string($var287___as_double2)))"/>
            </AL506C>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Another solution would be to check after the AL506C Tag and rename every variable under it.

Comment: just search string begin with "xsl:variable name=", save it into a dict.

Comment: @leaf_yakitori the weird thing is with the variable reference

Comment: you need show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the obvious language for transforming XSLT is XSLT, rather than Python.

You've got some very strange XSLT code there because the variables are declared and never referenced.

It is of course perfectly legal to have two variables in XSLT with the same name, especially if their scopes don't overlap (as here).

Renaming the variables is not difficult, the hard part is renaming any references to the variables. To do that you need to understand the scoping rules for variable references so that you can work out which variable each reference is pointing to. That becomes especially difficult if the scopes overlap. At this point the decision becomes, how general do you want your solution to be? Does it have to handle all edge cases? Or could you take a short cut, like assuming that a variable reference refers to the most recently declared variable with a matching name?

A correct solution requires complete parsing of every XPath expression in the stylesheet, and is therefore quite challenging. A hack that works most of the time might be rather easier. So at this point we need to understand a bit more about the project: what exactly are you trying to achieve? Why, for example, are the duplicate variable names actually a problem?